# Visualize Haskell Data Tree with graphviz

Tags: haskell, graphviz, dot

My attempt to visualize a Haskell Tree, was with Graphviz:

```
import Data.GraphViz.Types as G 

data Animal = Dog String | Cat String
data Stable = Stable [Animal] 

main :: IO ()
main= let myanimals=Stable [Dog "Max",Cat "Cooper"]
    in print $G.printDotGraph myanimals
```

The output should be dot-formatted, something like:

```
digraph {
    Stable -> Dog "Max";
    Stable -> Cat "Cooper";
}
```

However the Code yields an error message:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `dg0 n0' with actual type `Stable'
* In the first argument of `printDotGraph', namely `myanimals'
  In the second argument of `($)', namely `printDotGraph myanimals'
  In the expression: print $ printDotGraph myanimals
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The  [`graphviz`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz) package is for representing and manipulating graphviz-formatted graphs. It does not do anything for converting arbitrary data structures to graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must convert your data type to a graph that this package can render; it doesn’t do the conversion for you. It does allow converting an [fgl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl) graph to its `DotGraph` type. For that, you can construct a graph with one of the concrete graph types like [`Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.7.0.3/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-PatriciaTree.html) using the [`mkGraph`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.7.0.3/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html#v:mkGraph) function. Here’s an untested sketch of how you might do that. The specifics depend on the graph you want to produce. (It can be done much more compactly, but I’ve tried to be more explicit for illustration.)

```
type NodeLabel = String  -- Just the animal name.
type EdgeLabel = ()      -- No information for now.

graphFromStable :: Stable -> Gr NodeLabel EdgeLabel
graphFromStable (Stable animals) = mkGraph nodes edges
  where

    -- Define the set of nodes in your desired graph.
    nodes :: [LNode NodeLabel]
    nodes = stableNode : animalNodes

    -- Make an edge from the stable node to each animal node.
    edges :: [(Node, Node, EdgeLabel)]
    edges =
      [ (stableId, animalId, ())
      | (animalId, _animalLabel) <- animalNodes
      ]

    -- Define the stable node’s ID and label.
    stableNode :: LNode NodeLabel
    stableNode@(stableId, _stableName) = (0, "Stable")

    -- Give IDs and labels to each animal node.
    animalNodes :: [LNode NodeLabel]
    animalNodes = zip [1..] (map animalLabel animals)

    -- Get a label for an animal node.
    animalLabel :: Animal -> NodeLabel
    animalLabel (Dog name) = name
    animalLabel (Cat name) = name
```

Then you should be able to use `graphToDot` on the result of this function to convert it to the `DotGraph` type, and finally use `printDotGraph`.

(One of the other graph representations might allow you to do this more conveniently for your use case, e.g. using strings instead of integers as node IDs, but I’m not really familiar enough with these libraries to tell offhand.)

If you want something quicker and dirtier, an alternative is to print out the graph as a string of Dot source code. But I’d invest in using these structured types for anything nontrivial, since it will give you more guidance from the types, and let you use graph algorithms from FGL to analyse and transform your graph.

Answer (score 0):

Using [the `treeToGraph` function from here](https://github.com/mcandre/cspace/blob/fd5335005f6d9c286a2008decdfc225f9779560b/TreeToGraph.hs) you can do something like:

```hs
import TreeToGraph (treeToGraph)
import Data.Tree
import Data.GraphViz
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as LT
import qualified Data.Text as T

derivationToDotGraph :: Tree Int -> T.Text
derivationToDotGraph =
  LT.toStrict . printDotGraph . graphToDot def . treeToGraph
  where
    def :: GraphvizParams n nl el Int nl
    def = defaultParams
```